# Embedding Silverlight control in WPF app - is it possible?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

**Background:**
One of the most attactive feature of Silverlight is [PlanProjection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.planeprojection%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) because of its ease of use and the stunning effect. Unfortunatelly, it is not available in WPF. I know that similar effects can be achieved using Viewport3D but certainly not with that simplicity.

**The App:**
I would like to build a Win app designed for dualscreen computer, a bit similar to PowerPoint: 1 fullscreen viewer window for the audience, and 1 regular window to control the app.

**The problem**:
Building the app in SL is not very appealing: Going to fullscreen always requires user confirmation due to (understandable) security reasons. Detecting primary/secondary screens, their positions is only possible with [System.Windows.Forms.Screen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.aspx) class (pls, correct me if I am wrong), which is not available in SL.

**The odd solution:**
Would it be possible to write my controls in SL utilizing the fancy and simple PlanProjection features and reuse them within a WPF application?
If yes, what impact will I have on the installer? I assume that the installer would need to deploy both .NET framework and SL runtime.

Do you have alternative ideas to facilitate cherry-picking features from the two different worlds?

Comment: What I've done is create 2 projects SL and WPF with the same code.

Comment: It is impossible even to add reference to a silverlight class library. But I have a strange idea that you can try a browser or frame control and open xap file inside a WPF application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF has rich 3-D capabilities that are far greater than what Silverlight 4 can do so if PlanProjection is the main feature from SL that you require but want to create a desktop application then using WPF all the way would be the way to go.  WPF can do everything that PlanProjection can do.  Charles Petzold wrote an excellent book on WPF 3-D.

Comment: While WPF certainly can do all that SL PlanProjection does, they are in a completely different league as far as simplicity is concerned. Still, I will probably follow your advise using this component: http://blog.endquote.com/post/710116433/planeprojection-in-wpf

Answer (score 1):

Just use Planerator : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greg_schechter/archive/2007/10/26/enter-the-planerator-dead-simple-3d-in-wpf-with-a-stupid-name.aspx